# Poner fecha a un input

Tags: jquery

Amigos, tengo un input normal

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="fecha_y_hora_de_creacion">
```

y con ajax traigo el valor de este input que esta en una db y en el servidor esta asi:

**2018-05-24 17:58:44**

Como hago para cargar el valor al input si no puedo hacerlo de esta forma??

```
$('#fecha_y_hora_de_creacion').val(res[0].fecha_y_hora_de_creacion);
```

la variable **res[0].fecha_y_hora_de_creacion** es la que contiene el valor que viene de la DB y es **2018-05-24 17:58:44**

Gracias por la manito.

Answer (score 3):

Para setear el valor correcto, debes separar fecha y tiempo con una T asi:

```
$('#fecha_y_hora_de_creacion').val(res[0].fecha_y_hora_de_creacion.replace(' ', 'T'));
```